# How to create labels for outliers on frequency boxplots in R

Tags: r, label, boxplot, outliers, frequency-distribution

Is there a simple way to label boxplot outliers from within the boxplot command in ggplot2 (using `ggpubr`)? I am seeking to identify outliers for each variable on frequency boxplots. Previous answers do NOT address this type of boxplot. My x variable is `mhi` and my y variable is `postest`. My boxplot code is:

```
...
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))  
boxplot(covid$mhi,
        main = "mhi", 
        sub = paste("Outlier rows: ", boxplot.stats(covid$mhi)$out))  
boxplot(covid$postest, 
        main = "positive test rate", 
        sub = paste("Outlier rows: ", boxplot.stats(covid$postest)$out))  
...
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution, using the car package. Very simply,

```
Boxplot(covid$mhi, data=covid,labels=rownames(covid))
```

In this case, the rownames are simply the numbers of each entry in the column (covid$mhi) in the dataset. Now, how would I label each outlier with the corresponding designation in my first column, zipcode?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0RhA.jpg)